# force pureconfig to use -dconfig.file application.conf file and not resource application.conf

Tags: java, scala, typesafe-config, pureconfig

I have the following application.conf file:

```
# App
tables = [
    "table_1",
    "talbe_2"
]
```

and the following scala code:

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.auto._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import pureconfig.generic.ProductHint

case class Configuration(tables: Array[String])

object Config {
  implicit def hint[A] = ProductHint[A](ConfigFieldMapping(CamelCase, CamelCase))

  val conf = ConfigSource.fromConfig(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")).load[Configuration] match {
    case Right(conf) => conf
    case Left(failures) => throw new Exception(s"Unable to load the configuration ${failures.toList.mkString("\n")}")
  }
}
```

and to test the application.conf, I have this code:

```
object Test extends App {

  val res = Config.conf.tables
  println("hello")
}
```

when I drop application.conf in resources folder, it works. But It does not works when i use

`-Dconfig.file=C:/Users/path/to/application.conf`

It use the resources application.conf file despite the one in argument -Dconfig.file.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: also note, if you type it into (eg intelliJ), ensure it is VM options, not programe arguments ```-    <option name="PROGRAM_PARAMETERS" value="-Dconfig.file=./local.test.application.conf" />
+    <option name="VM_PARAMETERS" value="-Dconfig.file=./local.test.application.conf" />```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the call

```scala
ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
```

From scaladocs

> Loads an application's configuration from the given classpath resource
> or classpath resource basename, sandwiches it between default
> reference config and default overrides, and then resolves it.

You have to use

```scala
ConfigFactory.load()
```

which

> Loads a default configuration, equivalent to
> load(defaultApplication())

And `defaultApplication` supports `config.file`

> If the system properties config.resource, config.file, or config.url
> are set, then the classpath resource, file, or URL specified in those
> properties will be used rather than the default
> application.{conf,json,properties} classpath resources.